# Is having 0 motivation and 10% work performance and not resigning OK?

Tags: professionalism, resignation, ethics, unprofessional-behavior, motivation

I entered a company last month and I have 5 years of previous experience in that area. But there is a 4 year gap before entering this company.

They give me 2 projects and said, work on these. They sometimes asking how is it going, I am replying I am working on.

My motivation is died out. I go to work a few hour later. I work 1 or 2 hours in an 8 hours job.

As there are 2 projects, whoever asks how is it going I am replying I am working on other project. But in reality I waste time in the work.

I lost my curiosity and they give the long run projects. I feel like I am a city taxi, I couldn't travel from city to city. I can only do small modifications easiliy.

- I may request them to micro-manage me.
- I may request to assign me different projects.
- I may resign, feeling it is a bit unethical
- I may try to solve the problems internally never tell anyone about anything.
- I may request to motivate me.

I am asking you guys

1. What's the professional behavior?
2. What's the best in my specific case?

Comment: Not to be rude, but the reality is: You have two projects, that usually means there are two project managers. If none of them can figure out you're slacking, _joke's on them_.

Comment: We cannot really tell you how to feel, and whether you should be ok with something. As for whats the "professional" (whatever that means) thing to do when you are not doing your job, but still getting paid, I think you know the answer.  The actual question is, what do you want to achieve? Do you want to keep the job? Do you want to move to some other company, or field? What do **YOU** want?

Comment: @SouravGhosh for one project I made intern team mate do my work. In first project I seem to be successful with the help of the intern. The other project manager is giving tasks but not demanding.

Comment: @AidaPaul My previous memories about this field, decrease my motivation. Firstly I want to make a peace with this field then decide. In this time I try to increase my performance

Comment: @elections12 sorry I am still as confused as before. So you ultimately want to keep that job? Or just keep it while looking for new one?

Comment: Whatever else you do, go and talk to a doctor about this. You may have an issue that is nothing to do with your job that is affecting you.

Comment: +100 to @DJClayworth's suggestion to check with a doctor to make sure this isn't clinical depression, which is a treatable condition.

Answer (score 5):

This is a tricky one to answer - I suspect all the close votes are because the answers will be opinion based.

Here is my 2c.

There have been periods at various jobs where I felt my motivation waning. Sometimes it was because there wasn't anything 'interesting' to work on, sometimes it was because it was slow, sometimes it was due to external factors.

The first thing to say is that this is natural and happens to everyone to a lesser or greater degree at one time or another.

The question you need to **honestly** ask yourself is **why** you are feeling like this?

I'll give two scenarios to highlight what I mean.

At one job, it was a very, shall we say, monotonous job. I wanted advancement and it wasn't happening. The reality of that job was that it was a dead-end job due to a myriad of reasons (the company was running on borrowed time). I started to slack off, I pulled sickies, I put in less than the minimum effort. I then left and found a new job.

What I realised is that I should have started looking for a new job around 3-6 months earlier - but I was younger and didn't recognise the signs.

Job 2 - I wasn't feeling particularly appreciated by Management - I had put in a butt-load of effort for a project, which had gone well (not perfectly) and what I was expecting (Bonus/Pay rise etc.) was not forthcoming, so I was salty and as a result, started to slack off.

Now, what happened here is that there were things happening behind closed doors, but due to *reasons* they were taking time - once those things completed, suffice to say I got the acknowledgement I was seeking and that improved my motivation.

The point is:

"Is the reason you are feeling unmotivated temporary and is it related to work?" If the answer is Yes to the first one, I'd stick it out. If the answer if No to the first part and Yes to the second part - that's when it's time to switch jobs.

Comment: Yes, there always seem to be *reasons* :-)

Answer (score 2):

That is what work is.  It can not always be entertaining.  There often is a lot of mundane work that needs to be done.  But there can be periods of enjoyable, brain tasking activity too.

- You can stay there, be unethical and stagnate.
- You can take interest in your work and do it to the best of your ability (which is my goal always).
- Or you can look for another job and hope it is more enjoyable.

Comment: Stagnate: until you are fired, of course.

Comment: I build new stuff, or put lots of effort in to making what I was asked for the best. I can stay busy most of the time, but things I build or improve don't usually get used, so I find that disheartening.

Comment: It's not uncommon for a lot of a coder's output to go unused as project directions change. You may want to work on recalibrating your goals as being to do the best job you can, and to help guide the product toward being one worth releasing, rather than insisting that only release us success. In fact, sometimes the most successful result is quickly and clearly proving that the idea isn't worth pursuing further.